# I can't grab the session id with requests but i can take csrftoken why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

#Since I am using sessions, normally the session_id should be present in the cookies. However, as #you can see, it is not present in the cookies. When I perform the action in the browser, the #session_id is visible, but I couldn't achieve it with Python and requests.

```
payload = {
    "csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrfmiddlewaretoken,
    "this_is_the_login_form": this_is_the_login_form,
    "username": username,
    "password": password,}
headers = {"Origin": "https://www.postgresql.org","Referer": "https://www.postgresql.org/account/login/?next=/account/","User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}

post = session.post("https://www.postgresql.org/account/login/", data=payload, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

ou cannot access the session cookie because it is by default set to HTTPOnly.(You can see it using Firebug(Resources->Cookies->sessionid's HTTP column is checked))

Copying from the docs:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY
Default: True

Whether to use HTTPOnly flag on the session cookie. 
If this is set to True, client-side JavaScript will not to 
be able to access the session cookie.
```

You can set: SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False in your settings.py if you really want to have access to it from client side code. Nevertheless it not a recommended practice.